# Uniform Convergence of a function defined by an integral

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck with the following problem:
Let K be a real-valued function such that:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |K(t)|dt < \infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(t)dt = 1 $. Let f be a continuous function. Then we define:
$f_{n} (x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+ t/n)K(t)dt $. I want to prove that the sequence ${f_{n}}$ uniformly converges to f in any interval of the form $[a,b]$. I've thought about integration by parts, but you aren't given any hypothesis on the differentiability of either $K$ nor $f$. Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a side note, K kind of looks like the Dirac Delta. I'm not an expert on the topic, but maybe there are useful results in that context that can help with the problem

Comment: K is not the dirac delta since the dirac delta is not a function in the common sense and even if you look on the dirac delta as a function, it is infinity a point. Hence not real valued.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be bounded? What makes the integral defining $f_n$ converge?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $f(x) = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) K(t) \, dt$. It follows that
$$ |f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x+t/n) - f(x)| |K(t)| \, dt.$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I think so. Given epsilon > 0, since f is continuous you can find a large enough N such that for all n > N, |f(x+t/n) - f(x)| < epsilon . Then the epsilon gets out of the integral sign and the resulting integral is convergent by hipothesis. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a little more complicated than that because $f(x+t/n)$ may not be close to $f(x)$ for all $x$, rather just for $t$ inside a bounded interval. When $t$ is large you can use the fact that $|f(x+t/n) - f(x)|$ is bounded.